# Django test case failing

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

I am pretty new to Django and I ran into a problem. I am not even sure if its a stupid question or not. I want to test if my home view contains link to my topics view but despite everything being at place the test is getting failed. Any help appreciated .It shows the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/abc/Desktop/python-environments/second/tutorial/myproject/boards/tests.py", line 26, in test_home_view_contains_link_to_topics_page
self.assertContains(self.response, 'href="{0}"'.format(board_topics_url))
  File "/home/abc/Desktop/python-environments/second/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 369, in assertContains
self.assertTrue(real_count != 0, msg_prefix + "Couldn't find %s in response" % text_repr)
AssertionError: False is not true : Couldn't find 'href="/boards/1/"' in response
```

here are my files

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


app_name = 'boards'
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.home, name='home'),
path('<int:d>/', views.topics, name='topics'),

]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Board, topic


def home(request):
    boards = Board.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'boards/index.html', {'boards': boards})

def topics(request, d):
    board = get_object_or_404(Board, id=d)
    return render(request, 'boards/topics.html', {'boards': board})
```

index.html

```
{% load static %}<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Boards</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'boards/css/bootstrap.min.css'     %}">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <ol class="breadcrumb my-4">
        <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Boards</li>
      </ol>
      <table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-inverse">
          <tr>
            <th>Board</th>
            <th>Posts</th>
            <th>Topics</th>
            <th>Last Post</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {% for board in boards %}
            <tr>
              <td>
                  <a href = "{% url 'boards:topics' board.id %}"> {{board.Name }}</a>
                <small class="text-muted d-block">{{ board.description}}</small>
              </td>
              <td class="align-middle">0</td>
              <td class="align-middle">0</td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and lastly tests.py

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.urls import reverse, resolve
from .models import Board
from .views import topics, home


class HomeTests(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.board = Board.objects.create(Name='Python',description='Python discussion board')
        self.response = self.client.get(reverse('boards:home'))

def test_home_view_status_code(self):
    self.assertEquals(self.response.status_code, 200)

def test_home_url_resolves_to_home_view(self):
    view = resolve('/boards/')
    self.assertEquals(view.func, home)

def test_home_view_contains_link_to_topics_page(self):
    board_topics_url = reverse('boards:topics', kwargs={'d': self.board.id})
    self.assertContains(self.response, 'href="{0}"'.format(board_topics_url))
```

Comment: testing html content with raw strings operations can be a bit tricky (whitespaces, quoting etc). Better to use a proper HTML parser for this.

Comment: You have any good html parser in mind ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> self.assertContains(self.response,
>   'href="{0}"'.format(board_topics_url))

Didn't you forget spaces around `=`? Any way, you can open your page in browser and examine its html code.

Comment: Okay. Introducing space around "=" made the test pass. I am glad now but I still dont understand why it failed. The html code of my page when opened in browser doesnt have space around =.

Comment: Well, whitespaces are present in your template, so they are expected to be present in ```response```. Speaking about your browser - I hesitate to answer. Maybe you could give a screenshot?

Comment: I guess Firefox Inspector can reformat code for convenient reading. Try "View source" (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/View_source)